# How do I change the cursor of axShockwaveFlash?

Tags: c#, cursor, axshockwaveflash

I wanted to change the cursor into black. I searched many websites and ended up with a few answers, but they don't work with `axShockwaveFlash`. I have this:

```
Cursor = new Cursor(@"PathToCurFile");
```

It only changes the cursor of the form, but I want to change the control's mouse. I tried another option:

```
Cursor.Override = Cursor;
```

It doesn't do anything, I believe. So I tried this:

```
axShockwaveFlash1.Cursor = new Cursor(@"PathToCurFile");
```

Again, it does nothing. Would anyone tell me how to change the color of my cursor?

Edit1: i tried placing an invisible label ontop of it... Did change the mouse but i couldn't click on the game, So i tried to pass the clicks to AxShockwaveFalsh I could click etc but the cursor went back to normal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to do it at a lower level using a Win32 API. Here is the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;

using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
public class Form1
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr SetCursor(IntPtr hCursor);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern IntPtr LoadCursorFromFile(string lpFileName);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern bool SetSystemCursor(IntPtr hCursor, int id);

    private const uint OCR_NORMAL = 32512;

    static Cursor ColoredCursor;

    public Form1()
    {
        this.Load += Form1_Load;
    }
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.CenterToScreen();
    }

    private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        IntPtr cursor = LoadCursorFromFile("C:\\Whatever\\Whatever\\example.cur");
        bool ret_val = SetSystemCursor(cursor, OCR_NORMAL);
    }
}
```

I suggest changing the cursor in the axShockwaveFlash1 controls MouseEnter and MouseLeave events, eg:

```
this.Controls["AxShockwaveFlashObject1"].MouseEnter +=Form1_MouseEnter;
```

If it doesn't have these events place the axShockwaveFlash1 control in a PictureBox control and use its in/out mouse events.

Comment: works, but for future users trying this:

you should use Form1_FormClosed event and SystemParametersInfo
Or else the cursor won't ever get back to normal even if you kill the program

I'll give you the bounty but i should wait 8 hours